# How to remove /blog/ prefix for custom post types in permalinks?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a client that used to have a static website and a blog powered from WordPress under the `/blog` subdirectory. Now he decided to move everything into WordPress so that he can also create and edit pages easily. However because the website is getting a lot of traffic and he already has likes, tweets and +1 in every blog post he wants to keep his blog under the `website.com/blog`. I thought it was as easy as heading over the permalinks and add `/blog/%postname%/` in the permalink structure.

What the problem is right now is that I have a created a few custom post types to accommodate the needs of his content and custom post type's content resides now under the blog virtual directory.

How can I specify that only the blog posts and the blog categories must be under the /blog virtual directory and everything else can use the permalink structure of /%postname%/.

This is my custom post type

```
register_post_type( 'vm_products',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Products' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'New product' ), //in the horizontal bar when you are logged in.
            'add_new' => __('Add new product'),
            'add_new_item' => __('New product'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit product'),
            'new_item' => __('New product'),
            'view_item' => __('Show all products'),
            'search_items' => __('Search product'),
            'not_found' =>  __('No products found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No products found in trash'), 
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => 'Products'
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'show_ui' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'custom-fields', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product'),
    'taxonomies' => array('vm_product_cats')
    )
);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to setup your custom post types? There is an option in [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) called `rewrite` that allows you set the permalink options.

Comment: I added the custom post type code I am using. My items are becoming /blog/product/...

Comment: This worked for me [Remove slug from custom post type post URLs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls#answer-265707)

Answer (score 20):

Extend the `'rewrite'` argument to suppress the first URL part:

```
        'rewrite' => array(
            'with_front' => false,
            'slug'       => 'product'
        )
```

But using just `%postname%` for different post types is really tricky and error prone. Avoid it.

Comment: I did that trick but no luck. :( Thanx for trying to help though. To be honest the client is using /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/ but i did not thought that it has to do with my problem.

Comment: It didn't work in my case though. I have a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856537/remove-post-type-from-custom-post-type-permalink , Please answer

Comment: @Ramesh I'm not active on SO. Ask WordPress here please.

Comment: @fuxia Here it is sir: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342008/remove-post-type-from-custom-post-type-permalink?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using MULTISITE, then you need to just set the field in settings page:

[Remove the blog slug from Wordpress Multisite root node](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107901/remove-the-blog-slug-from-wordpress-multisite-root-node)