# Remove blog slug from WPMU?

Tags: multisite, permalinks, slug, site-url

i have wordpress MU, everything is fine in child sites , but in the main site in the permalink  structure have been changed itself , mean that after the site url it have like http://example.com/blog ,

most probably this is the site url, i have checked this in my db it still like http://example.com/ , what is wrong with my WPMU? have any guess ? i have followed everything in other posts like WPMU developers and so on , but no luck,

Also when, i have to go single page, it redirects into me on home page, so that i decided , this is the problem

check my attached screenshot for more details[image: screenshot]

Comment: Asked today: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107901/remove-the-blog-slug-from-wordpress-multisite-root-node/107903#107903

Comment: Already tried this, no working at all