# How can I remove the folder from a Multisite URL?

Tags: multisite, site-url

I necessarily have a multisite installation in a subfolder. For most of the Sites this is fine, but I would like to remove that folder entirely for another Site.

Like so:

```
http://example.com/banana/site1
http://example.com/banana/site2
```

but then

```
http://example.com/site3
```

Is this possible without using .htaccess and manual database changes?

Comment: Do you mean the stuff from your install, like this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/107903/170?

Comment: No, I don't think that applies in this case.

Comment: You can set custom url, it is not necessary, that you use the subdomain in each site.

Comment: Do you mean subfolder?