# How to eliminate permalink prefix in Wordpress Multisite

Tags: permalinks, multisite, errors, links, options

I have installed the multisite plugin for Wordpress; I have one website in English, and the other in French.

However, when I go to Settings -> Permalinks, my English website shows this: 
[image]

I don't understand why there's "/blog" in the permalink. Whereas in the French website, the Permalink is like this: 
[image]

Therefore when I go to a page and switch languages, the website says: "Oops! That page can’t be found. It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try one of the links below or a search?"

So I would like to eliminate the "/blog" prefix for the English website. However I'm a beginner in WP so I'm not sure if there's a better solution.

Thank you very much for your reply !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the blog slug from Wordpress Multisite root node](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107901/remove-the-blog-slug-from-wordpress-multisite-root-node)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/r3df-multisite-blog-slug-remover/ this removes the main site /blog slug.