# Is this possible? A multisite with "www.example.com/en/blog/" and "www.example.com/cn/blog/" (two directories deep)

Tags: multisite, multi-language

Is it possible to install a multisite and have the **first** installation here:

```
http://www.example.com/en/blog/
```

and then all **other** sites in these places?

```
http://www.example.com/cn/blog/

http://www.example.com/ru/blog/

http://www.example.com/jp/blog/
```

*Note that the first installation cannot be under `/en/` or just `/`*

**EDIT: See solution in my self-accepted answer below.**

Comment: Yes, that is possible. It can be sub domain also. like blog.example.com

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to any reference? I believe WordPress may only allow me natively to set up the multisite with `/en/blog/` `/en/blog/site2/` `/en/blog/site3/`. However, what I need is to be able to set up is multisite with different directories **above** the installation location, in this case swapping out `en`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. See my solution: wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/291790/135100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! The trick was writing a variable PATH_CURRENT_SITE definition after enabling and altering the additional site settings. Simple, and no other special htaccess rewrites or code needed.

### Step 1) Original installation

Under `https://www.example.com/en/blog/`

### Step 2) Enable multisite

https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

### Step 3) Add new sites

In the network admin, start with just adding each additional site under another subdirectory such as `ru` in `https://www.example.com/en/blog/ru/`. Then, edit the URL after creating it to `https://www.example.com/ru/blog/`. Repeat this step for more sites.

### Step 4) Edit `wp-config.php` file to define PATH_CURRENT_SITE dynamically

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com');
// Previously just: define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/en/blog/');
preg_match('/^(\/[a-zA-Z]+\/blog\/)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
if (!is_array($matches) || !isset($matches[1]) || !is_string($matches[1]))
{
    die('INVALID DIRECTORY');
}
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', $matches[1]);
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

### STEP 5) Cleanup permalink

To prevent double `blog` slugs like `/en/blog/blog/post-name/`, go to the site settings (in the network admin) and edit the permalink settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your requirements are possible.

As addition, you can also use different domains for each language, like

- `http://www.example.cn/blog/`
- `http://www.example.ru/blog/`
- `http://www.example.jp/blog/`

if you need also relationsships betweent the posts of different sites, in your context languages, you can realize this via custom code or an existing plugin, like [Multilingual Press](https://multilingualpress.org/).

---

Comment: I believe WordPress may only allow me natively to set up the multisite with `/en/blog/` `/en/blog/site2/` `/en/blog/site3/`. However, what I need is to be able to set up is multisite with different directories **above** the installation location, in this case swapping out `en`.

Comment: Your main installation should be without `en`, so that all languages are a directory after domain, like `example.com` for the main and `en`, `jp` as directory, NOT sub-domain. It is also possible to remove the `blog`, is only a change after installation in the settings of the Multisite and his permalink rules. You should also find good answers here on WPSE.

Comment: Yes, the `blog`can you remove after the install. see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/107903/170

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think you understand. What I mean is that my **original** installation MUST be installed inside `example.com/en/blog/`. This we cannot change. We must install this there. Then enable multisite and have the new site "ru" use the path `example.com/ru/blog/`.

Comment: But you can also use a Sub site as main site, so that you rewrite the `example.com` to  `example.com/en/blog` I use this often for Admin Dashboard with lot of information etc. not for users, front- and back end.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but unfortunately, due to client restraints, we cannot alter their existing non-WordPress site under example.com root.

Comment: Thanks for your help. See my solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/291790/135100

Comment: A regex search in each url is not really fast, depend from the size of the install. Also is in my mind not possible, a update of the permalink structure is enough.