# Custom taxonomy returns 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, templates, url-rewriting

I'm getting a 404 page when I visit my custom taxonomy page.
Custom taxonomy is called 'manufacturer'.
I also have a cpt called 'product'.

**EDIT 1:**
It has something to do with the cpt rewrite. If I disable the rewrite, taxonomy works fine.

Few notes:

- permalinks flush doesn't help
- template taxonomy-manufacturer.php exists
- WP version is 4.4.2
- wp category has base 'kategorie'
- post url is set to 'Post name'
- cpt should have 'pretty url' (without any prefixes)

This is CPT 'product':

```
        function product_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Products', 'Post Type General Name' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Product', 'Post Type Singular Name' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Products' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Product' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Products Archives' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Product:' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Products' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Product' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Product' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Product' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Product' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Product' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Product' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Product Not found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Product Not found in Trash' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into product' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this product' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Products list' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Products list navigation' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter products list' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Products' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Product Description' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/'),
        'has_archive' => true
    );
    register_post_type( 'product', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'product_post_type', 0 );
```

And this is custom taxonomy 'manufacturer':

```
    function manufacturer_taxonomy(){
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Herstellers', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Hersteller', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Hersteller' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Hersteller' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Hersteller' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Hersteller:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Hersteller' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Hersteller' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Hersteller' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Hersteller Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Hersteller' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'manufacturer', 'product', array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'hersteller',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
    ));
}
add_action('init','manufacturer_taxonomy',0);
```

Any idea would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a rewrite slug of `'/'`. Note that using a slug of `''`, which you will find floating around, will not work for the latest WordPress versions either.  If you want a url like `http://domain.com/custom-post`, there are no bullet-proof solutions, but the answer to this question will give you some leads: [Remove slug from custom post type post URLs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls)

Comment: I did another wp installation, and changed the wp default "posts" to "products" ( and other labels attached to "posts" ), set permalinks to /%postname%/, and everything works fine.
Removed the old cpt "products" and that's it.
I think this is maybe the cleanest solution tomy problem. Not perfect, since it's post type "post", but it works.