# Make custom post available under main domain directly?

Tags: permalinks, shortlink

i have a custom post type called project.

The shortlinks are all

www.myapp.com/project/project-slug

i want to change that to

www.myapp.com/project-slug

someone knows what I have to change in, i reckon permalinks settings, to be able to do that?

Comment: What are your Permalink Settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this before 6 months ago. But I don't remember the way. But I bookmarked a few  articles which I followed to do it.Just check it.

[Remove slug from custom post type post URLs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls)

[Remove The Slugs from Custom Post Type URL](https://colorlabsproject.com/tutorials/remove-slugs-custom-post-type-url/)

[Remove Custom Post Type Slug from Permalinks](http://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/)

Comment: the first post answered my question i think.

(the second post is the same like the first one)