# Dynamic URL and pass the data to an iframe

Tags: urls, iframe

I have a WordPress marketing site (`www.example.com`) and a backend app site (`app.example.com`). What I am trying to do is this:
if some body goes to the URL:

```
www.example.com/profile/<<profileId>>
```

I want to create a page that has mostly generic content and one `iframe` with `src`

```
my.example.com/profile/<<profileId>>
```

Now I have 2 problems:

1. Can a page have dynamic URL? If i try to set the URL to `www.example.com/profile/*/` it becomes `www.example.com/profile/`
2. If I do get the page to work, how to pass profileId to the `iframe src`?

Can somebody please direct me to a plugin/solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

Create a page with slug 'profile' in your WordPress Dashboard.

**Step 2**

Use this function to register `profileId` var.

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'wp233_query_vars');
function wp233_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'profileId';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

And add a rewrite rule to wordpress like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wp233_add_rewrite_rules' );
function wp233_add_rewrite_rules() {

  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^profile/([^/]+)?$',
    'index.php?pagename=profile&profileId=$matches[1]',
    'top');

}
```

**Step 3**

Now you can access the query var like this:

```
http://yoursite.com/profile/xxxx/
```

Now you should be able to extract the profileId by hooking in suitable action

**Example**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp233_get_profile_id' );
function wp233_get_profile_id() {

   $profile_id = get_query_var( 'profileId' );
   if ( $profile_id ) {

    // do some magic work. you now captured the profile id
    // which was passed to url.com/profile/{ID}/ -> here.

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too difficult. First you have to get the `<<profileID>>` part of the current page/post. How to get it, depends on what it is and where in your template you are calling it. If, for instance, "profile" is a custom post type, then `<<profileID>>` is the slug of the post, which you could retrieve like this, presumably in `single.php`:

```
$profileID = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post());
```

The rest is straightforward PHP:

```
echo '<iframe src="my.example.com/profile/' . $profileID '/></iframe>';
```

Now you have your page with the `iframe` and you want to display it without the slug. The answer to that is [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls).

Comment: Any help here on a similar question please? :) https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339370/wrap-wordpress-site-in-iframe

Comment: Technically speaking the other question is the same as this one.