# Remove wp directory and slug for custom post type from the URLs

Tags: custom-post-types, urls, htaccess

I see there is an answer here for slugs [Remove slug from custom post type post URLs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls) but I would also want to remove the directory from the url.

Because my custom post type has under 10 articles I think it is better to just hardcode it in .htaccess maybe?

So the end goal is:

```
http://example.com/blog/slug/post-title/
```

to become

```
http://example.com/post-title/
```

I suppose in my root .htaccess I would have to put something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/slug
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/index.php  [L]
```

But I don't understand what should I insert in wordpress .htaccess to point to that article...

Any idea how to do this in .htaccess?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer you linked does exactly that, does it not work for you? Have you flushed your permalinks after making your code changes?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic that answer removes just the slug, not also the directory.

Comment: Have you got with_front false in your rewrite args?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic yeah I had it. i had to insert something in my root .htacess file so that it redirects to the blog folder. otherwise wordpress will not get hit. thanks