# Remove CPT slug from URL

Tags: custom-post-types

This question has been asked so many times, and i have viewed every answer in this meta, and outside.

Still none are functioning in Wordpress 4.9.5 (latest version).
The enhancement asked 3 years ago is still waiting: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34136#ticket

**How to remove the Custom Post Type slug name from the url, without creating issue to previous posts or pages?**

I've tried the following solutions:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204210 - 404 page
https://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/ - 404 page
http://www.codeinhouse.com/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/ - 404 page

Answer (score 1):

Change permstruct for your CPT.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_permastruct( 'tvshow', '/custom_home_page/%tvshow%');
}, 11);
```

However, this is a complex question and can involve different steps to make it work in different ways.

P/S/
don't forget to flush url rules.

Comment: Can you explain the solution?

Comment: You changing permstruct of your post type. You adding any base you want which I assume your desired state, a changed permstruct will care about generated rewrite rules and future links generation.

Comment: I don't want any base. What is the rule to delete the slug before the %postname%?

Comment: I don't recommend to do this. In such case, it will collide with pages. You need to learn first to use `rewrite_rules`, once you master it you will be able to create own structure. Even one you want to have.

Comment: The purpose of this question is to do this.