# Removing custom post type slug from URL

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I want to remove custom post type slug from URL and for this I have used this solution [Removing slug from custom post type URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls#answer-204210)

It is working fine but I also want to add category with custom post type name but when I tried to add category slug then it started to redirect to 404 page. I have added category to URL using Custom Post Type Permalinks plugin.

When I remove the code that I have added for removal of post type slug then category base URL also works but both these things are not working together.

For this I have tried many solutions and at the end I got same result.
So for my website 
example.com/postype/category/postname works 
example.com/postname also works
but 
example.com/category/postname redirects to 404 page. I update permalinks as well but nothing is working in this case. I will really appreciate your help.