# How To Use htaccess to Rewrite Link Structure for a Page that is Generated Programatcially

Tags: plugins, php, url-rewriting, htaccess

My site uses a plugin Easy Digital Downloads, which creates products that are of url structure, `sitename/downloads/{Product}` I want to change them to `sitename/{product}`

For example, https://milyin.com/downloads/steve-jobs-reality-is-malleable/ is one of my product, i want to make it appear at https://milyin.com/steve-jobs-reality-is-malleable/

For this they provide ability to change slug `define('EDD_SLUG', 'my-downloads-slug');` via php, in this use case, i could change it to something else, but not blank, the default slug is `downloads` and i wanted no slug, so made it blank, which didn't work.

I rather tried using htaccess, I am having trouble with that too.
I tried this: `RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*)$ $1`

But it had no impact andmy links remained same, so please help me rewrite them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to remove a post-type slug completely from the url. This is documented in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204210/45740). Remember that after making any changes to post urls, you should resave your permalink structure for the changes to fully take effect.

**Edit:**
You can additionally redirect from the old location (with the slug), this way:

```
function na_redirect_slug_requests() {
    $post = get_queried_object();

    // If our custom-post-type
    if ( ! empty( $post->post_type ) && 'events' === $post->post_type ) {
        $url = get_permalink( $post );

        // And the custom-post's url doesn't match the one we're looking at...
        if ( false === strpos( $url, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {

            // Then let's redirect.
            wp_safe_redirect( $url, 301 );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'na_redirect_slug_requests', 10, 50 );
```

Just remember to replace "events" with your custom post type slug.

Comment: Hey there i tried your solution, turns out it works partially.... It shows the content on 'Siteurl/{product}/' but it also shows content on 'siteurl/downloads/{product}/'

Comment: I don't want it displayed with slug... You can check, https://milyin.com/steve-jobs-reality-is-malleable/ and https://milyin.com/downloads/steve-jobs-reality-is-malleable/ sjow same thing

Comment: I've added code to the answer to redirect from the original location.

Comment: I had lost hope that anything would ever work. But then your beautiful lines of code appeared. It works, it jist works, freaking Thank you....